# xcode 4.3.2 how to change view using modal segue programmatically

Tags: storyboard, modal-dialog, nstimer, segue

hey guys i need help in this situation where i need to transfer to another view using modal segue after 4 seconds.. but when i ran this all it shows is a blank view.. is there something wrong that i did.. im really still a newbie with xcode any ideas/suggestions is really very helpful.. thanks this is my code..

```
-(void)onTimer
{
    mainInt += 1;
    if(mainInt == 4)
    {
        Game2ViewController *gameStart = [[Game2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"Game2ViewController" bundle: nil];
        [self presentModalViewController: gameStart animated: YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `mainInt`?

Comment: its just an integer for me to compare the time..

Comment: why you did not set timer to 4 seconds?

Comment: ohh its okay i solved the problem..-(void)onTimer
{
    mainInt += 1;
    if(mainInt == 4)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextView" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NextView"]) 
    {
        Game2ViewController *gameStart = [[Game2ViewController alloc] init];  
    }
}

Comment: you better reply to the question yourself and accept answer.

Comment: okay thanks for having the interest in my question anyway.. really appreciate it..

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)onTimer 
{ 
mainInt += 1; 
if(mainInt == 4) 
{ 
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextView" sender:self]; 
} 
} 
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{ 
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NextView"]) 
{ Game2ViewController *gameStart = [[Game2ViewController alloc] init]; } }
```